# como heredar en scala de una clase con un único constructor con parámetros

Tags: intellij-idea, scala

estoy colaborando con un plugin de idea, y debo extender la siguiente clase de Java

```
public abstract class AbstractBlock implements ASTBlock, ExtraRangesProvider {
  public static final List<Block> EMPTY = Collections.emptyList();

  protected final @NotNull ASTNode myNode;
  protected final @Nullable Wrap myWrap;
  protected final @Nullable Alignment myAlignment;

  private List<Block> mySubBlocks;
  private Boolean myIncomplete;
  private boolean myBuildIndentsOnly = false;

  protected AbstractBlock(@NotNull ASTNode node, @Nullable Wrap wrap, @Nullable Alignment alignment) {
    myNode = node;
    myWrap = wrap;
    myAlignment = alignment;
  }
.
.
.
```

Intenté hacerlo de esta manera

```
class RuleBlock(node:ASTNode,wrap:Wrap,alignment:Alignment,spacingBuilder:SpacingBuilder) extends AbstractBlock(_,_,_){
.
.
.
```

y aunque el IDE no me marca error, al compilar me da el mensaje

> :unbound placeholder parameter

¿Cómo puedo especificar correctamente los tipos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El símbolo '`_`' es un *placeholder* que se usa para indicar (entre muchas otras cosas) que no vas a usar este argumento. Aún así, el compilador necesitar saber siempre el tipo de los argumentos, por eso te da ese error.

Lo más habitual es poner los mismos argumentos que usas en tu clase:

```scala
class RuleBlock(
    node: ASTNode,
    wrap: Wrap,
    alignment: Alignment,
    spacingBuilder: SpacingBuilder
) extends AbstractBlock(node, wrap, alignment)
```

Aún así, la clase java usa anotaciones para indicar que algún argumento puede ser `null`. Aunque estas anotaciones son de uso interno de IntelliJ, en scala3 se podría indicar también mediante una unión, algo así:

```scala
class RuleBlock(
    node: ASTNode,
    wrap: Wrap | Null,
    alignment: Alignment | Null,
    spacingBuilder: SpacingBuilder
) extends AbstractBlock(node, wrap, alignment)
```

No te aseguro que funcione. No uso java, ni IntelliJ. Asegúrate de revisar la [documentación](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/experimental/explicit-nulls.html#java-interoperability) sobre cómo interopera scala y java al respecto.

Comment: justo así lo resolví, mi forma de entenderlo como dev Java es la siguiente(por si lo quieres incluir): así como al poner parentesis depués de la clase estamos haciendo lo que en java entenderíamos un constructor, al pasarle los parámetros es como pasarle los parámetros a la clase padre en el constructor, cosa que en Java se haría llamando a super, y en Scala no hay necesidad de complicarse de más la vida con ámbitos.

Comment: Así es, en scala en la definición de la clase va implícito su "constructor" principal, único modo de crear instancias y que será usado por el resto de constructores `def this(...)` u otros métodos factoría. No obstante, se puede hacer _privado_ este constructor principal, lo que impedirá su uso desde subclases al estilo super.